# How do I get the default checkout url for a magento store?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to send a user to checkout programmatically in Magento.  I can send them to `$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');` but if they have some sort of third party checkout extension I won't be using the proper one.  Is there a way to get the default checkout url for the site and redirect there?

Comment: In cart.phtml, it has `<?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>`, which is to list all the checkout methods available for the site.  If `getMethods()` returns only one method, then there is a default checkout URL. What if it returns more than one method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default checkout link is returned by `getCheckoutUrl()` function of `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Link` class. If is quite simple:

```
public function getCheckoutUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage', array('_secure'=>true));
}
```

3rd party extensions will most likely override this class (i checked OneStepCheckout 1.4 and it works like this).

Comment: That looks like it's exactly what I need.  However, when I create a new Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Link object it tells me that function isn't defined.

Comment: I ended up using this in a Front Controller `Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl()`

Comment: This won't work well if the site uses only multishipping checkout.

Answer (score 21):

you can try with

```
$checkout_link = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
```

this return checkout link in all conditions

- while using any extensions such as OnePagecheckout or OneStepcheckout
- if on extension were used it simply returns the basic checkout url

Comment: It's untrue that `Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();` returns checkout link in all conditions. It always returns the onepage checkout URL: `$this->getUrl('checkout/onepage', array('_secure'=>true));` So, it won't work well if the site uses only multishipping checkout.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't always work. For us, with Magento 1.9, it returns http://<my-store-name-in-here>/onestepcheckout/ and upon trying to redirect to that URL, Magento says "The one page checkout is disabled."